# import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice in a module

Tags: java, android, module, bluetooth

I am trying to break parts of my app out into a reusable module.

Now, a class in my module that is trying to import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice cannot resolve the symbol.

Here is my gradle script for the module:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile files('libs/Android_Platform_Adapter.jar')

    compile files('libs/wisepadapi-android-2.7.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/emvswipeapi-android-2.12.3.jar')
}
```

This is the first module I've worked on.  I'm sure it's something easy.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the mismatch. You are trying to import `import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice` inside a strictly `java` module (`apply plugin: 'java'`).

You should create android library module. Create a new **Phone & Tablet** module as described [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-app-module.html).

Comment: Will that still build as a jar?